# HTML + CSS Text over images crossfade blocks the crossfade from happening

Tags: html, css, button, text, overlay

it's my first question here. So far I managed to find all my answers by searching, but not now.

I created a simple crossfade image effect that works as highlight of menu buttons. Next I wanted to put some text over it, but it turned out that hovering over text blocks the crossfade effect from triggering. I could generate static images for each menu item, but I am wondering if there is a simple solution that could prevent bloating the site with redundant images.

Code that's problematic:

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/halfblack/2MCWm/4/

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="42">
            <div id="cf">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>Sample text</span>
                    <img class="bottom" src="http://i.imgur.com/ffYHwLW.png" />
                    <img class="top" src="http://i.imgur.com/t3TW5LG.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="42">
            <div id="cf">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="bottom" src="http://i.imgur.com/ffYHwLW.png" />
                    <img class="top" src="http://i.imgur.com/t3TW5LG.png" />
                </a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {height:100%;}

}

#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:42px;
  width:172px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;

}

#cf a {
  text-decoration:none;}

#cf span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;

}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `#cf span:hover ~ img.top{opacity:0;}` to it does the trick.
When hovering over a span, it triggers the same thing it does to hovering over the images themselves.

Altough this is your question answered, I recommend simply using background images on your tds, instead of pasting multiple images over and over again.

I've got this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32adu/) for you, where your code is very much optimized.

Comment: Thanks, that span hover indeed does exactly what I wanted. The problem with td tags is that smooth crossfade doesn't seem to work in Firefox while it does with my code.

Comment: @Halfblack Then again. Endlessly pasting images to fade in and out is not-done. You could create a div inside every td with background images. Maybe you could leave the tds transparent, and use the :before  pseudo element to make these images render behind them. If you want me to help any further by making a Fiddle, just ask :)

Comment: I never said it's the perfect solution, only that it's a working one :) Nevertheless I'd be glad to see some other helpful solutions.
I tried going with div background fading on your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/32adu/1/ but on Firefox effect is the same - transition happens in an instant, without crossfade.